# What is the difference between Fisherian vs frequentist statistics?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, frequentist, philosophical

I just read a research paper that said implicitly that there was a difference between the two. I thought that Fisherian statistics was another word for frequentist statistics.

Comment: I don't know a ton, but came across this same idea the other day. Didn't Fisher believe in a strong middle-ground between Frequentist vs. Bayesian Statistics?

Comment: Having the paper for context would help. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_statistics) suggests that while Fisher was frequentist, not all frequentists agreed with Fisher.

Comment: Maybe it was referencing fiducial inference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_inference?

Comment: You'll need to explain the context. Fisher got involved in a lot of controversies over his long career & every so often someone uses "Fisherian" to label his side of the argument on a particular issue.

Comment: The question is clear and the answer can be found in [chapter 4 of *Computer Age Statistical Inference* by Efron & Hastie](https://hastie.su.domains/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf): "Sir Ronald Fisher was arguably the most influential anti-Bayesian of all time, but that did not make him a conventional frequentist. His key data-analytic methods—analysis of variance, significance testing, and maximum likelihood estimation—were almost always applied frequentistically. Their Fisherian rationale, however, often drew on ideas neither Bayesian nor frequentist in nature, or sometimes the two in combination."

Comment: Moreover, whole chapter 4 can serve as a long answer to this question, and Figure 14.1 on page 265 locates different statistical methods within a triangle whose corners represent the Bayesian, frequentist and Fisherian approach.

Comment: Another comparison of the Fisherian approach with the Bayesian and the frequentist approaches can be found in [Bradley Efron. "R. A. Fisher in the 21st Century (Invited paper presented at the 1996 R. A. Fisher Lecture)." Statist. Sci. 13 (2) 95 - 122, May 1998.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-13/issue-2/R-A-Fisher-in-the-21st-century-Invited-paper-presented/10.1214/ss/1028905930.full); see in particular Figure 1.